# How to set Persistence for presented page number?

Tags: tabulator

Is there any setting to store the current presenting page number like as `persistentLayout:true`?

I created Back Button with `history.back();` that always back to first page of table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built in way of doing this, but you could use the ***pageLoaded*** callback to store the current memory in local storage:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    pageLoaded:function(pageno){
    //pageno - the number of the loaded page

       localStorage.setItem('currentPage', pageno);
    },
});
```

And then on page load set the page of the table after you have instantiated it with the ***setPage*** function

```
table.setPage(localStorage.getItem('currentPage') || 1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your supported answer.